# Tax on foreign sourced income while residing in Bolivia

Tags: foreign-income, bolivia

I am an Australian citizen with permanent residence in Bolivia.
I plan to sell PDFs on  Canada and USA-based websites which will take commission and pay me monthly and quarterly respectively.
Do I pay tax in Bolivia on this foreign income?

Comment: It might depend on the details and how actively you are managing the creation and sales of the product. If it is deemed that ["business activities (are) carried out in Bolivia"](https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/global/Documents/Tax/dttl-tax-boliviahighlights-2018.pdf?nc=1) then maybe.